# How to store binary input in a C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, bit

I understand I can use the library **bitset** to handle binary input and operations on it.

I want to **xor** certain bits on the input and perform **shifting** in the binary sequence the user has entered.

I think it can be done in an array, but how can I put each bit in an array element?

An example will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can operate directly on the `std::bitset` as if it were an array, because the `[]` operator is conveniently overloaded for you, e.g.

```
std::bitset a, b, c;

for (i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];    // c = a XOR b
```

(Note: this assumes that `a`, `b` and `c` all have the same size.)

Comment: May I ask what does it mean that [] operator is overloaded?

Comment: In C++ operators can be overloaded in much the same way as functions and methods. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading